# Java DOM parsing get only parent elements

Tags: java, parsing, dom

I have the following xml:

```
<categories>
    <category id="1">
        <name>XML</name>
        <category id="2">
            <name>XPath</name>
        </category>
        <category id="3">
            <name>XML Schema</name>
        </category>
        <category id="4">
            <name>XSLT</name>
        </category>
        <category id="5">
            <name>XSL-FO</name>
        </category>
        <category id="6">
            <name>XQuery</name>
        </category>
    </category>
</categories>
```

I'm trying to parse this using DOM. I want to get the parent category and want to have output looking like the following:

```
Current element: category
Id: 1
```

I'm using the code below but am not getting the right output. How can I fix this?

```
NodeList xmlCategories = document.getElementsByTagName("category");
for (int i = 0; i < xmlCategories.getLength(); i++) {
    Node category = xmlCategories.item(i);
    if (category.hasChildNodes()) {
        System.out.println("\nCurrent element: " + category.getNodeName());
        if (category.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) category;

            System.out.println("Id: " + element.getAttribute("id"));
        }
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Current element: category
Id: 1

Current element: category
Id: 2

Current element: category
Id: 3

Current element: category
Id: 4

Current element: category
Id: 5

Current element: category
Id: 6
```

Comment: And the output you expect to see is?  Oh, category name. I get it. Try not to make people reverse engineer your code to determine expected output. There are guidelines here for posting a good question. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh that's the second block of code, I see why that's confusing. I'll edit it

Comment: Please first when you edit, accept my edits. I shifted it to the left to make it readable.

Comment: I accepted it but I'm not sure it looks different?

Comment: I moved it to the left, it required too much scrolling to the right to read.  Also your output does not match the code. You don't print "Name:" anywhere. *please* keep them synchronized.

Comment: I've done stuff like that with JavaScript before but not for a long time. What I remember is, that in some cases what you're looking for is nested one level deeper than you presume, and in other cases errors come from when you think you're trying to display the value of a node but it is really an attribute or vice versa.  You should be able to fiddle with it a bit to get the values you want. They are there!  Just look at the DOM definitions again very carefully.  Also use the browser debugging feature or add on to see how it is laid out in memory. That usually clears it up.

Comment: E.g. Browsers either have built in or add on/plugin support for displaying the DOM tree of the current page you're visiting. Shows the full hierarchy and nesting.  You can compare what you see there to where your code is looking for something and find it.  I know there is at least one case where the DOM puts a name or text a level deeper than one thinks it would be.

Comment: Well, which value to output is another topic altogether. In the xml there are categories within categories and I would like to get just the containing category (for example, with id=1 in above xml code).

Comment: Again best way I've seen to do that is use DOM viewer/debugger in a browser to see what the hierarchy looks like after the HTML/XML is loaded into memory.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what exactly you want here.  Are you saying you want to only display a `category` element if its `id` is equal to a given value such as `1`?  Because it seems like you already have the code in place to do so. You just need to add a conditional checking what the `id` is.

Comment: I wanted to display the category that contains other categories, in this xml example it would be the one with id=1. But I solved it with element.getElementsByTagName().item(index). If I wanted only the first element the index would be 0. I also realized in the code above printing out the id is fine, but printing out the name elements not. At least, not with that code. But thanks for your assistance. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NodeList xmlCategories = doc.getElementsByTagName("category");

    outer : for(int i=0;i<xmlCategories.getLength();i++){

        Node category = xmlCategories.item(i);

        if(category.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

            NodeList childrenCatgory = category.getChildNodes();

            inner : for(int j=0;j<childrenCatgory.getLength();j++){
                Node childCat = childrenCatgory.item(j);

                if(childCat.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                    if(childCat.getNodeName().equals("category")){
                        Element catEle = (Element) category;
                        System.out.println("Current element: "+category.getNodeName());
                        System.out.println("Id: "+catEle.getAttribute("id"));

                        break outer;
                    }



                }
            }               

        }       

    }
```

I suppose this should do it.If a catagory element has a child called catagory, that's the parent and that's where I break out. 
The output is:

Current element: category

Id: 1